# How can I reduce the filesize of a graal native image?

Tags: clojure, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I have this project: https://github.com/crinklywrappr/repoman

It's very short (~150loc).  When I run `lein native-image` it produces a massive <s>4gb</s>3gb binary (at least on windows).

I believe there are a couple of reasons for the size:

1. <s>--allow-incomplete-classpath is required due to an error compiling clj-http-lite.  ([this](https://github.com/borkdude/clj-http-lite/commit/c0c1269d449e3e5648ae9e803c49f0eb3f100247) may have fixed it)</s> Including this commit reduced the size by 1gb.
2. [JCA security services](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/JCASecurityServices.md) adds some size, and the devs are looking into ways of reducing that.

I've never made a native image with graal before today.  What steps can be taken to reduce the binary size of a graal native image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the graal was reporting memory consumption during compilation, and I was mis-attributing that to filesize.